# Help me in showing that there is only 2 solutions for $f(x)=(x-1)e^{2x}+x^2-x-1=0$?

Tags: calculus, functions

**I have a problem with part (b) in the following question**

**Question**

a) Function: $f(x)=(x-1)e^{2x}+x^2-x-1$, show that $f(x)$ has a zero between −1 and 1/2 and between 1/2 and 2.

**b)** Show that there are only exactly two solutions (two 0's).

---

**My Approach**

a) **Pretty easy:**
$$f(x)=(x-1)e^{2x}+x^2-x-1=0$$
$f(-1)>0,f(1/2)<0$ Intermediate Theorem tells that there is a solution.

$f(1/2)<0,f(2)>0$ Intermediate Theorem tells that there is a solution in between.

**b)** This is where I have the problem with, how do I show exactly that there is only 2 solutions. The most obvious thing that came to my mind is that the **highest power is 2**. But then I thought it can't be that easy, there is something I am missing.

Comment: For b you can try to show that $f$ is piecewise monotone; i.e. $f'(x) >0$ for $x>1/2$ and $f'(x) < 0$ for $x<1/2$.

Comment: @Winther Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not too hard. Just prove that $f(x)$ is monotonic on the intervals $( - 1,{1 \over 2})$ and $({1 \over 2},2)$.
Hence, you may compute the derivative to get

$$\eqalign{
  & f'(x) = {e^{2x}} + 2(x - 1){e^{2x}} + 2x - 1  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \left( {2x - 1} \right){e^{2x}} + 2x - 1  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \left( {2x - 1} \right)\left( {{e^{2x}} + 1} \right) \cr} $$

you can easily verify what I said by the above formula.

Comment: Just a small thing regarding the first sentence: To prove that there are only two zeros alltogeather we don't just need monotonicity on $(-1,1/2)$ and $(1/2,2)$, but on $(-\infty,1/2$ and $(1/2,\infty)$.

Comment: Ooops! you are right! :) I was just thinking over those intervals but not over $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing rough curves for $e^{2x}=-x+1/(x-1)$.
[image: curves]